# PHP incomplete linkifying

Tags: php, regex

Basicaly, I found some code here:

> http://buildinternet.com/2010/05/how-to-automatically-linkify-text-with-php-regular-expressions/

which automaticly turns text links into click-able links.

There is however an error which I can't discover as I am not very good with regex, which is that it doesn't fully capture the text or something like that. As shown here:

> https://gyazo.com/f279a3a2bedd8a078713d45f971ab65d

Code:

```
function link_filter_offence($player_complaints_offence_raw)
        {
            $player_complaints_offence_raw= preg_replace("/(^|[\n ])([\w]*?)((ht|f)tp(s)?:\/\/[\w]+[^ \,\"\n\r\t&lt;]*)/is", "$1$2&lt;a href=\"$3\" &gt;$3&lt;/a&gt;", $player_complaints_offence_raw);
            $player_complaints_offence_raw= preg_replace("/(^|[\n ])([\w]*?)((www|ftp)\.[^ \,\"\t\n\r&lt;]*)/is", "$1$2&lt;a href=\"http://$3\" &gt;$3&lt;/a&gt;", $player_complaints_offence_raw);
            $player_complaints_offence_raw= preg_replace("/(^|[\n ])([a-z0-9&\-_\.]+?)@([\w\-]+\.([\w\-\.]+)+)/i", "$1&lt;a href=\"mailto:$2@$3\"&gt;$2@$3&lt;/a&gt;", $player_complaints_offence_raw);
            return($player_complaints_offence_raw);
        }

$player_complaints_offence_raw = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=klXTQjmfVeg&feature=youtu.be';
$player_complaints_offence_raw = link_filter_offence($player_complaints_offence_raw);

$reply = html_entity_decode($player_complaints_offence_raw);
echo $reply;
```

Sorry if I couldn't have been more detailed, but I have no clue how to solve this at this moment in time.

Comment: In the regex, you will see ...\n\r\t&lt;.... That &lt; should be a <. It looks like you copied HTML source code, which changes < to &lt;

Comment: Ye, the pattern `&lt;` in the example you used didn't html encode properly, just change it to `<`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
function link_filter_offence($player_complaints_offence_raw)
        {
$player_complaints_offence_raw= 
preg_replace("/(^|[\n ])([\w]*?)((ht|f)tp(s)?:\/\/[\w]+[^ \,\"\n\r\t<]*)/is", "$1$2<a href=\"$3\" >$3</a>", $player_complaints_offence_raw);
$player_complaints_offence_raw= 
preg_replace("/(^|[\n ])([\w]*?)((www|ftp)\.[^ \,\"\t\n\r<]*)/is", "$1$2<a href=\"http://$3\" >$3</a>", $player_complaints_offence_raw);
$player_complaints_offence_raw= 
preg_replace("/(^|[\n ])([a-z0-9&\-_\.]+?)@([\w\-]+\.([\w\-\.]+)+)/i", "$1<a href=\"mailto:$2@$3\">$2@$3</a>", $player_complaints_offence_raw);
            return($player_complaints_offence_raw);
        }

$player_complaints_offence_raw = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=klXTQjmfVeg&feature=youtu.be';
$player_complaints_offence_raw = link_filter_offence($player_complaints_offence_raw);

$reply = html_entity_decode($player_complaints_offence_raw);
echo $reply;
```

all what I did is that i have escaped the second parameters of your preg_replace functions , and it's works perfectly for me